# Inserting from selecting in Spark causes OOM

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark SQL is like this :

```
INSERT INTO new
SELECT
~~~
FROM A, B
WHERE
~~~ (complex join)
```

Schema for A and new is same, and B has some patterns for filtering.
And size of B is small, which is broadcasted.

But it displays OOM error at my local test.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.copy(UnsafeRow.java:535)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.copy(UnsafeRow.java:93)
```

I tried repartition, and some configuration changes(like spark.shuffle.memoryFraction), but it didn't work.

I'm using Spark 1.6.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is, try to increase executor memory

```
 --executor-memory 4096m
```

You can also try to tune "spark.memory.fraction" and "spark.memory.storageFraction" as given in
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/tuning.html#memory-management-overview